# how can I let my shell script with 1 argument accept default unix commands in the command line

Tags: shell, unix

I need to write a shell script for finding the mode of the files and the code needs to be able to accept other Unix commands as optional arguments.

for example:

```
mycode 644 ls -l
```

should perform the command ls -l on all files in the current directory that have mode 644.
I only need to know what aspects of shell scripting help me here to run the `ls -l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for you the best will be to use find.

So for example the operation you are looking for can be executed by this simple comand:

```
find . -perm 0644 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Your script may look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
perm=$1
shift
find . -perm $perm $* {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
mode=$1
shift
$*
```

It removes the first parameter into a variable, and executes the rest as a single shell command. It doesn't attempt to handle `mode`, but you indicated that your question wasn't about that.